# OpenSSL: Verifying a certificate against a CRL returning "unable to get issuer certificate" on OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan

Tags: macos, openssl, keychain, chain, certificate-revocation

I am using following script to verify the certificate against crl on OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.

```
host=wikipedia.org
port=443

openssl s_client -connect $host:$port 2>&1 < /dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/p' > $host.pem

crlurl=$(openssl x509 -noout -text -in $host.pem | grep -A 4 'X509v3 CRL Distribution Points' | grep URI |  grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^"]+')

curl $crlurl -o $host.crl.der

openssl crl -inform DER -in $host.crl.der -outform PEM -out $host.crl.pem

OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=':' certificates=$(openssl s_client -connect "$host":"$port" -showcerts -tlsextdebug -tls1 2>&1 </dev/null | awk '/BEGIN CERT/ {p=1} ; p==1; /END CERT/ {p=0}' | sed 's/-----BEGIN/:-----BEGIN/g'); for certificate in ${certificates#:}; do echo $certificate | tee -a $host.chain.pem ; done; IFS=$OLDIFS

cat $host.chain.pem $host.crl.pem > $host.crl_chain.pem

openssl verify -crl_check -CAfile $host.crl_chain.pem $host.pem
```

It is working fine on ubuntu but throwing following error when trying to run on OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan.

```
wikipedia.org.pem: C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate
```

Connecting wikipedia.org with s_client returns :

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Comment: It seems that in linux OpenSSL is reading root certificate from the truststore. I tried adding root certificate to the chain manually for mac. Its working with this approach. But why we need to add the root certificate manually to the chain. Is there any way to retrieve root certificate with chain?

Answer (score 0):

The CA issuer of wikipedia.org is present in truststore i.e *cacerts.pem* in your ubuntu which are mostly located in

```
lib/security/cacerts
```

& is absent in your OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan. truststore

```
$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

Use following command to view SSL certificate chain & try appending root CA of wikipedia.org to your mac truststore

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername wikipedia.org -connect wikipedia.org:443
```